# Display records with matching column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following structure.

```
Name   Age 
----------
John   20    
Jack   20    
John   18
Steve  15
Jack   16
Lewis  17
Don    19
Jack   21
John   21
John   18
```

The output needs to be filtered and only displayed when Jack and John share the same age, similar to the below format. I tried using several approaches, however couldn't get the absolute result.

```
Name   Age 
----------
John   20    
Jack   20    
Jack   21
John   21
```

Comment: This is limited to Jack and John only?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

```
SELECT a.name, a.age
FROM (SELECT name, age FROM a) a, (SELECT name, age FROM a) b
WHERE a.name <> b.name AND a.age = b.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **`SELF JOIN`** and get the rows having different names and same age with only has names John and Jack.

**Query**

```
select t1.name, t1.age
from your_tabel_name t1
join your_tabel_name t2
on t1.name <> t2.name
and t1.age = t2.age
where t1.name in ('Jack','John')
group by t1.name, t1.age
order by t1.age, t1.name;
```

**[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8093c9/1)** is a sql fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

Have a cte that returns only Jack and John rows. Do a self join:

```
with cte as
(
    select name, age
    from tablename
    where name in ('Jack','John')
)
select t1.*
from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.name <> t2.name and t1.age = t2.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    SELECT * 
        FROM YourTable WHERE AGE IN
        (
        SELECT Age 
        FROM YourTable 
        GROUP BY AGE 
        HAVING COUNT(1)=2
        )D
    ORDER BY AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ! Try this as Most Simplest

```
SELECT a.name, a.age FROM xx_ages a,xx_ages b WHERE a.name <> b.name AND a.age = b.age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.* 
from empp a  
join empp b 
on a.age=b.age 
and  a.name in ('Jack','John') 
and a.name!=b.name 
order by a.age
```

Comment: Hello! Please format your code to look nice! Also, please consider adding a few words to your answer *why* the shown code helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8093c9/11

Using a `self join` and compare `rowid`

```
select
    t1.name, t1.age
from
    tblNames t1
    join tblNames t2 on
        t1.rowid <> t2.rowid and        
        t1.name <> t2.name and        
        t1.age = t2.age
where
    t1.name in ('Jack','John') 
order by t1.age, t1.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this :

```
select t1.name, t1.age from table1 t1
join table1 t2 on t1.age=t2.age and t1.name <> t2.name;
```

This is not limited to `Jack & John` only!

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ddd5d/1)